# Getting Mobile Phone number from Facebook OAuth

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

Can we get mobile phone number of the user when we are using OAuth for Login.
If the answer is "Yes" then what is the scope/permission I have to use?
Thanks in advance for your help!

-Narendra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the phone number from the graph api.  Best you can do is the email address if you request the email permission.